# $a_{n}b_{n} \rightarrow 0$ if $(a_{n})$ is bounded and $(b_n)$ converges to $0$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

I have trouble proving the problem below. Any tips?

Suppose that $(a_{n})$ is a bounded but not necessarily convergent sequence and that $(b_n)$ is a sequence converging to $0$. Prove that $a_{n}b_{n} \rightarrow 0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Let $M$ be a bound for $|a_n|$ and note that
$$
0\leq |a_nb_n|\leq M|b_n|
$$
for all $n$.
Now use the Squeeze theorem.

Comment: @JacobBlack Well, I think that he/she can take it from there, now.